# What is the difference between database caching and pooling

Tags: database, sqlite, vapor

I am mostly interested in the general concept, but specifically I need to understand this concept in order to learn server side programming with Swift/Vapor. But it's fine to get a generic answer even if you don't know Swift/Vapor.

I found out that in order to connect to a database, I can use these two methods:

```
func requestPooledConnection<Database>(to dbid: DatabaseIdentifier<Database>) -> Future<Database.Connection>

func requestCachedConnection<Database>(to database: DatabaseIdentifier<Database>) -> Future<Database.Connection>
```

Now what I understand from the documentation (Source: https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/database-kit/overview/#pools) is:

- With pooling I can reuse an existing connection, or create a new one if none exists
- With pooling connections are not shared between event loops, in order to prevent race conditions
- There is **usually** one pool per database per event loop
- With caching, you get one connection per database ID

Now that's a bit confusing, specially the term 'usually' and I also tried to search more documentation about the general concept (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool), and it looks like the words 'caching' and 'pooling' are used interchangeably sometimes. Now I am interested in understanding the difference because this would be useful in order to optimise correctly my web services. But to me it looks like - at least for how I understand Vapor's documentation - they're very similar concepts, and I don't get the difference. Can somebody clarify that?

Answer (score -1):

Caching is saving database SQL Temporarily and pooling is keep connection to database